# .NET framework crash or is my code faulty?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I created a class with 2 same classes inside:

```
public class Operation
{
    public Operation A;
    public Operation B;
    // ...
}
```

Inside this class I've put method with this code:

```
if (/* ... */)
{
    Operation temp = this;
    this.A = temp;
    this.B = new Operation(number);
    return true;
}
```

Exactly when `this.A = temp` is executed AND I try to see the result - expand the object in Locals (or watch) tab, my Visual Studio crashes. When I leave it running it will be fine until I try to check my object. The object also doesn't seem to be changing inside, I tried to get some data through code (like `myObject.A.A.A.Value` <- `double?` type) and it returns just nothing, and skips to another code line.
I'm 90% sure I'm missing something simple and it's my code fault, but I don't know what it could be, any help? : )

Edit:
I drew [something](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJgQt.png) to help you understand the method's job:

Comment: Are you trying to make an object inside your class declaration?

Comment: 99.9999999% percent of the time I ever ask myself this question, it is my fault :)

Comment: So, `this.A` equals `this`? An what will `this.A` have? It's infinitely recursive, I believe that's what's causing the crash. Why would you want to save an object inside one of it's own properties?

Comment: `this.A = this`? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem. Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: And tell us the version of the Visual Studio you use.

Comment: I had a very bad experience with the newest VS2015 expression evaluator. It displays internal errors or hang or break debugging session sometimes, doesn't work with Reflection members, can't evaluate complex LINQ. So...

Comment: I drew something! To help you understand the method's job.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/72519827/split.png

Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 12.0.30723 update 3 
however i tried running it on
Visual Studio Community 2015 14.0.24720 upadate 1

Comment: You might want to add the definition of your `ToString` method - the debugger automatically evaluates that, so if there's a problem with your infinite recursion, it can cause a `StackOverflowException` and nothing can prevent that. Also, is this a normal method, or a constructor?

Comment: Also, that drawing doesn't correspond to your method. You really need to think about your data structure in a different way - you don't even have a tree any more, which will likely cause a brazillion of problems with your code.

Comment: It is normal method, it fills "Values" inside this tree, and when it comes to expanding the tree - putting the whole tree into a branch of a new tree - the problem occurs.
I will try to think about different data structure, but still I don't understant what's wrong with this one and why it does not work : |

Comment: @TVOHM I'd argue that's not true, especially with the fairly recent release of the new Roslyn compiler. If you look at the amount of bug issues on their GitHub page, you'll see just how many things users can find. The C# people at Microsoft are only human too. I've had many weird things happen to me, then magically disappear after I restart VS or my PC - don't tell me that was my fault too?

Comment: The new debugging engine in VS2015 is quite buggy, much like everything else in VS2015.  You can get another opinion with Tools > Options > Debugging > General > tick the "Use Managed Compatibility Mode".  If it doesn't crash anymore then you know it is a debugger bug.  Just keep going, it happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it somehow *is* your fault, but Microsoft should indeed have protected Visual Studio against this crash by some algorithm.

The reason it crashes is possibly a `StackOverflowException` appearing when VS tries to evaluate your object for the "Locals" or "Watch" tab.

Since you effectivly set `this.A = this` the evaluation process recurses infinitely. To evaluate `this.A` it wants to evaluate `this.A.A` which obviously is `this`, too. So it also wants to evaluate `this.A.A.A` etc... and `A` will never be `null` cause it is always the same instance (`this`) again.

As stated above, VS *should* not crash anyway. So you may want to report this to Microsoft (never did something like this, I think http://connect.microsoft.com/ is a way to go).

Comment: Thanks, the idea i came with, seemed pretty logic and solid to me, but uh.. I will try to figure something else out : ( 

Thanks anyway!

Comment: The problem was,  `Operation` was passed by reference, thatwhy it came up recursing infinitely. After I created constructor which is duplicating passed object it began working, the question is, should it be this way?

Comment: @Zyraf Nice find! I think VS should never crash no matter what the developer does. So I suggest reporting to Microsoft anyway.